# How to get VARCHAR2(n) limit using OCCI?

Tags: c++, oracle11g, occi

I have a table with multiple VARCHAR2(n) columns ('n' differs for each column). I access the table from a C++ application via OCCI library. Is there a way to get this limit value (n) for a column using the OCCI library?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using MetaData. Here is the sample:

```
MetaData metaData = connection->getMetaData((utext*)L"\"TableName\"", MetaData::PTYPE_TABLE);
vector<MetaData> metaDataVector = metaData.getVector(MetaData::ATTR_LIST_COLUMNS);
for (UINT i = 0; i < (UINT)metaDataVector.size(); i++)
{
   if(metaDataVector[i].getInt(MetaData::ATTR_DATA_TYPE) == OCCI_SQLT_CHR)
      columnInfo.size = metaDataVector[i].getInt(MetaData::ATTR_DATA_SIZE);
}
```